# Have a common base type for all my custom annotations

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, annotations, java-annotations

So, I have created several custom annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Foo {

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Bar {

}
```

Those annotations are used in my functions:

```
public class Worker {

   @Foo
   public void doTaskOne() {...}

   @Bar
   public void doTaskX() {...}

   ...
}
```

I want to use java reflection to check if certain annotation is declared in one method.

```
for (Method m : methods) {
      if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Foo.class)) {
        ...
      } else if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Bar.class)) {
        ...
      }
}
```

The problem is that since in Java, custom annotation `@interface` is not able to be extended. I mean this is illegal:

```
public @interface Bar extends MyBaseAnnotation{
}
```

That's I am not able to have a base `@interface` for all my custom annotation class `Foo` and `Bar`. So, if I have a new custom annotation created, I need to add more `else if` condition in above method checking code, which sucks!  Is there anyway to get rid of this problem? What I want to achieve is to generalize my method checking code to :

```
for (Method m : methods) {
     if (m.isAnnotationPresent(MyBaseAnnotation.class)) {
         ...
     }
}
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your custom annotations with a base custom annotation, like [composed annotations](https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-meta-annotations-in-java) do.

Instead of:

```java
public @interface Bar extends MyBaseAnnotation{
}
```

use:

```java
@MyBaseAnnotation
public @interface Bar {
}
```

Comment: Annotation of annotations? How am I supposed to use this tactic in my method checking method?

Comment: With a simple helper method, like the one @AndrewTobilko showed in his answer. If you are using Spring, you could take a look at [AnnotationUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
@Parent
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Foo {}

@Parent
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Bar {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@interface Parent {}
```

and there is a method

```
public static boolean isAnnotationPresent(Method method, Class<? extends Annotation> parentAnnotation) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    for (Annotation methodAnnotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
        if (methodAnnotation.annotationType().isAnnotationPresent(parentAnnotation)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you can do

```
isAnnotationPresent(m, Parent.class)
```

---

You got it right: there is no inheritance between annotation types in Java. You could make your own rules, though. By saying "if annotation B has annotation A over it, then B extends A", you define the rule that you will follow while using reflection.

Comment: Can I have method in parent annotation so that the method checking function can call it for all my annotations? In other words, all "inherited" annotations inherit this method? `public @interface Parent {
    String value() default "";
}`

Comment: No, you can try to use/copy similar mechanism as Spring uses, but it's pretty complicated one, and requires creating whole own annotation API and implementing own annotations at runtime using own proxy classes. As then you could read data from parent annotation and copy it to child ones when your api method is used. But I would not suggest such hacky solution in any situation. Maybe try to simplify your annotation usage instead.

Comment: But if you will want to do it anyways @Leem.fin I can try to help a bit more